# Frequency lists derived from copyrighted works

Tags: copyright, fair-use, online-piracy

If someone were to publish word frequency lists derived from copyrighted films or books on their website would this constitute fair use, or be a breach of copyright?

The word frequency lists would simply consist of a list of individual, unique words found in the film/book and how many times each word occurs, ordered in terms of frequency.

Comment: It's quite possible -- likely even -- that it is neither fair use nor a breach of copyright.  A word frequency list is not a copy of a work in any meaningful way.  It's an analysis of the work.

Comment: To phoog’s point, this is no more a breach of copyright that writing a review about the film or book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequency of words appearing in a given work is a fact. It is not protected by any copyright on the work. Nor would it be protected by any copyright on an article, essay or other publication reporting such a frequency list. Facts, including this one, are not protected by copyright at all (See [17 USC 102(b)](https://copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#102) for US law on this. Other countries have similar laws). This is no more protected than a statement such as:

> J Random Author published a book last moth entitled *Adventures of Authors*.

Facts **about** a work are in no way protected by the copyright on the work.
The requirement of originality in a work for copyright to apply in US law was strongly stated in [*Feist Publications, Inc., v. Rural Telephone Service Co.*, 499 U.S. 340 (1991)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_Publications,_Inc.,_v._Rural_Telephone_Service_Co.) (the *Feist* decision). However the rule that facts are never protected by copyright goes back at least to the 1909 US copyright act, and I think to the [Statute of Anne (1710)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_Anne), the first somewhat modern copyright statute.